# How to send data from STM32 USB port to Raspberry PI USB port?

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, usb, stm32, embedded-linux

I want to send data through USB between STM32 and Raspberry Pi. I don't want to use USB to Serial convertor, but instead have a actual USB Connection (maybe CDC class). I have to send data at high rate (Full speed). Please guide on how to achieve this?

Comment: Getting USB working sounds complicated. The Pi has serial capabilities on 2 of its GPIO pins, that can be activated. The STM32 probably gives you quite a few serial peripherals on their GPIO pins. You could then do serial communications directly between the Pi and the STM32 without using a USB to serial converter. Is that likely to be a working solution for you?

Comment: @blippy, the data needs to be transferred at a higher rate( up to 12Mb/s ), which is not possible with UART serial or SPI. So only option is to use USB communication(FullSpeed-12Mb/s). How do you think this can be achieved between pi and stm32 controller?. My STM32 board supports host as well as device functionality and works with Low speed or Full speed.

Answer (score 1):

A USB-serial connector is simply a microcontroller implementing a USB CDC/ACM virtual COM port and bridging to a UART which you would connect to a microcontroller's UART interface.

In your case you can simply implement the CDC/ACM directly on the STM32 using either of its USB device controller peripherals (USB support varies depending on the specific device https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00296349-usb-hardware-and-pcb-guidelines-using-stm32-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

How you actually implement that will depend on what specific part, and what library or framework ecosystem you are using (e.g. SPL, CubeMX, Mbed). There are reference implementations, examples, drivers and libraries for all of these.

Your milage may vary, but I have measured ST's own USB library and example CDC/ACM virtual COM for STM32F1xx on a 72MHz MCU achieving 700kbits/s.  Note that the performance is independent of the baud rate you might set on the host when you open the he VCP. Setting the baud rate simply sends a control packet to the device that can be used to set the baud rate of a UART in bridging applications.  In your case such control packets can be ignored.  There are similar packets for modem control signals such as DTR, RTS, CTS and RI, which you might choose to us for flow control or other signalling.